Turn cell values into columns in MySQL
I have a table that looks like this:
|  EMAIL  |  LIST   |   STATUS     | ISP_GROUP   |  SENT_DATE   |  CREATED_DATE   |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| email1  |  list1  |   active     |    GMAIL    |  2024-06-01  |  2024-05-30     |
| email1  |  list2  |  complain    |    GMAIL    |  2024-06-12  |  2024-05-10     |
| email2  |  list1  |  unsubscribe |    YAHOO    |  2024-05-25  |  2024-05-01     |
| email2  |  list2  |   active     |    YAHOO    |  2024-06-15  |  2024-05-15     |
| email2  |  list3  |   active     |    YAHOO    |  2024-06-20  |  2024-06-11     |

An email can be on multiple LISTs and have a different STATUS for each LIST.
An email will only ever have be on ISP_GROUP.  In the example above, email1 is a GMAIL account.  email1 could be on 12 LISTs but will always be a GMAIL account.
I need to make each LIST into it's own column, then list the STATUS for each list in a subsequent column, and also have the SENT_DATE and CREATED_DATE in their own columns.
Here is an example of what I'm trying to achieve:
| EMAIL  | ISP_GROUP | LIST1_STATUS | LIST1_SENT_DATE | LIST1_CREATED_DATE | LIST2_STATUS | LIST2_SENT_DATE | LIST2_CREATED_DATE | and so on.. |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| email1 | GMAIL     |    active    |    2024-06-01   |      2024-05-30    |   complain   |    2024-06-12   |     2024-05-10     | 
| email2 | YAHOO     |  unsubscribe |    2024-05-25   |      2024-05-01    |   active     |    2024-06-15   |     2024-05-15     | 

So something like that.
There are 15 list total, then the results would be a really long dataset. If the email is not on a particular LIST, then it can be NULL.
I have written a query like this:
SELECT 
`email` 
,`isp_group`
, GROUP_CONCAT(`Lists`) AS 'Lists'
FROM `list_main` 
GROUP BY `email`, `isp_group`
ORDER BY `email` DESC

That returns a result like this:
|   EMAIL  |   ISP_GROUP  |         LISTS          |
----------------------------------------------------
|   email1 |   GMAIL      |  list1, list2          |
|   email2 |   YAHOO      |  list1, list2, list3   |

But I want to make each LIST their own column as well as the DATES.  How can I do this?

What does "An email will only ever have be on ISP_GROUP" mean? Did you mean "An email will only be in one ISP_GROUP"?

Do you have to do it in SQL? It's much easier in an application programming language.

@Barmar - Yes.  An email will only be on one ISP_GROUP.  I hadn't thought about  building an app for it.  I could do something with PHP.  But wouldn't I still have to write a query?

@Barmar - On second thought, I'm not sure an application would work.  There are 35 million total records, with almost 8 million DISTINCT email records.  I'm not sure how that would work.

Aren't you eventually going to display the results in the application? That's when you do the grouping and table generation.

This is basically a pivot, but you're generating the columns numerically instead of using values in the table as the column names. You could use the ROW_NUMBER() window function to produce the sequential column name for the pivot.

A common solution in PHP is to use GROUP_CONCAT() in the query, then use explode() in PHP to split them up and create the columns in the table.

@Barmar - I wasn't planning on displaying the records in an application.  More than likely, the records would be exported in a CSV.

So you use PHP to create the CSV.

The main difficulty is that you have to do 2 passes. The first pass is needed to find out the maximum number of rows in each group, so you know how many columns to produce in the header line.

A query returns a fixed number of columns, independent of table contents.

@Barmar - what if I created a table, and made 15 columns for the LISTs, 15 columns for the STATUS, 15 columns for the SENT_DATE, and 15 columns for the CREATED_DATE, then somehow send the data from my main table over to the new table?

That's the same problem -- how to do the "somehow send" step.

@Barmar - So the main table is derived from a set of 14-15 CSV files.  The files are the single LIST and the emails associated with that LIST.  Maybe I could build a table with all of these columns, and import the records to fill in the columns for their respective LIST.  And if the email already exists, it would just append.  I hope that makes sense.  Thoughts?

See the duplicate question I just linked to, it shows how to do it using ROW_NUMBER().

@Barmar - I see the question, and I definitely would like to try that because it appears to solve my problem.  But, the version of MySQL that I am using is (I believe) 5.6 or 5.7, so the functions necessary are not available.

If you know there are exactly 15 lists, you can make a query with 15 joins and explicitly name the columns. Not a pretty query, and probably not very efficient.

@Rudie - My main table holds 35 million records which were combined from 15 different tables.  So LIST1 was it's own table, and so on.  Are you suggesting that I INNER JOIN the main table with the 35 million records, or JOIN on the 15 LIST tables to create the results I need?

If you can't use window functions, you may need to write a stored procedure using a loop.

But doing it in PHP will almost certainly be easier than a MySQL SP.

If you know there are at most 15 lists, things are easier, since you don't need to count the max number first.

@Barmar - There are 14 lists as of right now.  That may go up in the future, but it's currently 14.

As I said, it's a little more complicated if you have to deal with a dynamic number. But you could just update the code when it goes up.

@Barmar - I'll consider trying that, but what do you think about creating a large table and appending it with each of the list values?

If you mean updating that table whenever you update this table, keeping them in sync may be a problem.

I agree with @Barmar, I would not do this in mysql, but in a proper programming language or use some kind of an ETL tool to do the transformation.

This is a SQL Anti-Pattern. The current format is normalised and so is the correct structure for SQL / Relational-Databases.  This begs the question; Why do you want to do this? What functional requirement do you think this would solve? xyproblem

@MatBailie well, almost normalized. Fully normalized would have a separate table with the email and ISP_GROUP columns, and this table would only use the key from that other table.

Also: MySQL 5.7 has gone end-of-life. It's abandonware now, and no longer gets any updates... not even critical security patches. It's time to move off of it; continued use is what the lawyers on the other side of the table might eventually characterize as "gross negligence".

A pivot query with a variable number of columns always requires two passes. You need to know how many columns, because an SQL query must have a fixed set of columns in its select-list before it begins reading data. You can't make an SQL query that expands itself based on the data it reads.
Here's an example of a query that produces the pivot table you describe:
SELECT
  email,
  MAX(isp_group),

  -- columns for list1
  MAX(CASE list WHEN 'list1' THEN status END) AS LIST1_STATUS,
  MAX(CASE list WHEN 'list1' THEN sent_date END) AS LIST1_SENT_DATE,
  MAX(CASE list WHEN 'list1' THEN created_date END) AS LIST1_CREATED_DATE,

  -- columns for list2
  MAX(CASE list WHEN 'list2' THEN status END) AS LIST2_STATUS,
  MAX(CASE list WHEN 'list2' THEN sent_date END) AS LIST2_SENT_DATE,
  MAX(CASE list WHEN 'list2' THEN created_date END) AS LIST2_CREATED_DATE

  -- repeat the set of three columns for each list, up to the max number of lists

FROM list_main
GROUP BY email;

Output given your sample data:
+--------+----------------+--------------+-----------------+--------------------+--------------+-----------------+--------------------+
| email  | MAX(isp_group) | LIST1_STATUS | LIST1_SENT_DATE | LIST1_CREATED_DATE | LIST2_STATUS | LIST2_SENT_DATE | LIST2_CREATED_DATE |
+--------+----------------+--------------+-----------------+--------------------+--------------+-----------------+--------------------+
| email1 | GMAIL          | active       | 2024-06-01      | 2024-05-30         | complain     | 2024-06-12      | 2024-05-10         |
| email2 | YAHOO          | unsubscribe  | 2024-05-25      | 2024-05-01         | active       | 2024-06-15      | 2024-05-15         |
+--------+----------------+--------------+-----------------+--------------------+--------------+-----------------+--------------------+

Dbfiddle, tested with MySQL 5.7: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/gjxHuzM7hKeyidVu8Q7GGj/0
Writing such a query requires you run an initial query to discover what lists exist:
SELECT DISTINCT list FROM list_main;

Given the result of that query, write application code to loop through the lists and format the columns of the pivot query.
The alternative, as the comments above suggested, is not to do the pivot in SQL, but just fetch all the data as it is stored in the database, and write application code to arrange it into the tabular presentation you want.
One way or the other, you need a client application where you can write the code to do the pivot.

This appears to have worked for me, albeit the query takes a while to run.  I'll take steps to fix that.  One question: when you say that I'll need a client application, you are referring to the query or writing an application code.  Is that correct?

Application code.
